# Custom entity and extended entity one to one association

Tags: php, shopware, shopware6

I am writing a shopware 6 plugin that adds a custom entity and associate it via a one to one association with an existing entity.

This are the important parts of my custom entity:

```
class OAuthUserDefinition extends EntityDefinition
{
  [...]
  protected function defineFields(): FieldCollection {
    return new FieldCollection([
       (new IdField('id', 'id'))->addFlags(new Required(), new PrimaryKey()),
       (new FkField('customer_id', 'customerId', CustomerDefinition::class)),
       new OneToOneAssociationField('customer', 'customer_id', 'id', CustomerDefinition::class)
     ]);
   }
}
```

And i extended the customer entity like this:

```
class CustomerExtension extends EntityExtension{
  public function extendFields(FieldCollection $collection): void {
    $collection->add(
      (new OneToOneAssociationField(
        'oAuthUser',
        'id',
        'customer_id',
        OAuthUserDefinition::class
       ))
     );
  }
  
  public function getDefinitionClass(): string
  {
     return CustomerDefinition::class;
  }
}
```

This is my migration:

```
    public function update(Connection $connection): void
    {
        $connection->executeUpdate('
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `nt_oauth_user` (
              `id` BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
              `customer_id` BINARY(16) NULL,
              `oauth_user_id` VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
              `created_at` DATETIME(3) NOT NULL,
              `updated_at` DATETIME(3) NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
              CONSTRAINT `fk.oauth_user.customer_id` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`)
                REFERENCES `customer` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
        ');
    }
```

And my service.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <services>

        <service id="Nt\OAuthClient\Core\System\OAuthUser\OAuthUserDefinition">
            <tag name="shopware.entity.definition" entity="nt_oauth_user" />
        </service>


        <service id="Nt\OAuthClient\Core\Checkout\Customer\CustomerExtension">
            <tag name="shopware.entity.extension"/>
        </service>

    </services>
</container>
```

Now with this code shopware breaks totally and i get an HTTP-error 503 on most of the Endpoints. I think it runs into a recursion because if i set the OneToOneAssociationField autoload property to `false` in the customer extension the 503 error vanishes. But the `store-api/v1/account/customer` gives me a

```
"status": "500",
"title": "Internal Server Error",
"detail": "Argument 1 passed to Shopware\\Core\\System\\SalesChannel\\Api\\StructEncoder::encode() must be an instance of Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\Struct\\Struct, null given, called in /app/vendor/shopware/platform/src/Core/System/SalesChannel/Api/StructEncoder.php on line 214",
```

because `customer->extensions->oAuthUser` is `null`.

If i swap it, set OneToOneAssociationField autoload on the extension back to `true` and to `false` in my custom entity everything seems to work but that is not very practical.

The recursion part of it seems like an error in shopware to me or do i have an error on my side? Do i need to supply a custom struct somehow?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.
Added an extension on product entity.
In my custom definition class (e.g. OAuthUserDefinition) I've set autoloading to false.
And I left autoloading to true in extension class (e.g. CustomerExtension).

No more infinite loop.
I guess the 2 classes were trying to load each other but the instances of the classes were other always. Would not know exactly.
I saw in shopware code that there are a few examples using `OneToOneAssociationField`.
This is why I'm not autoloading in both objects.
To this point I do not know if this infinite loop is a bug or miss use of code features.

I still got errors in admin on edit product page.
The only way that worked was to fill my table with NULL/empty values for all products. Also having in migration script something like:

```
$this->updateInheritance($connection, 'product', 'myLoremIpsum');
```

will create a column `myLoremIpsum` in `product` table.
I had to put the value from field `id` from table `product`.
I saw what value to put by installing this example:
https://github.com/shopware/swag-docs-bundle-example

https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/how-to/indepth-guide-bundle/introduction?category=shopware-platform-dev-en/how-to/indepth-guide-bundle

Would be nice to have official documentation and an example with `OneToOneAssociationField`.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I gave you an upvote but i think it is not a real answer to the question so i wont accept it. I opened an issue in the shopware issue tracker maybe they can say if it is a bug or a feature :D https://issues.shopware.com/issues/NEXT-11012

Answer (score 0):

Did you define a getDefinitionClass-Function in your CustomerExtension-Class?

```
public function getDefinitionClass(): string
{
    return CustomerDefinition::class;
}
```

Could your also please share your Database-Migration?

Comment: Yes i have an getDefinitionClass-Function in my extension.
I added it and my migration to the question.

Comment: Sure, i also added it to the question.